# Deserializing object is overwriting all values

Tags: angular, typescript, deserialization

Let's say I'm getting a list of products from a database, and trying to deserialize the data using the class below:

```
export class Product 
{
    constructor() { this.CartQuantity = 1 }

    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Price: number;
    CartQuantity: number;
}
```

The database only holds `Id`, `Name` and `Price`, while CartQuantity only exists in the project.  If I deserialize like so:

```
products: Product[];

getProducts() {
   this.ProductService.getAllProducts(
     (response) => {
        this.products = response;
     }
  );
}
```

`CartQuantity` is then undefined for every product.  The only solution I know of is to add a for loop after getting the response to set it to 1. But if I have many functions that fetch similar data, adding a loop to each seems like a bad way to do it.  Is there another way to do it similar to having a constructor setting it automatically?

Edit: Here's the service function that fetches the data:

```
getAllProducts(
    onSuccess,
    onFail = (reason) => console.log(reason)) {
      var url = SOME_URL;
      var req = this.httpClient.get(url);
      var promise = req.toPromise();

      promise.then(
        onSuccess,
        onFail
      );
    }
```

Comment: post the `ProductService.getAllProducts` function

Comment: Sorry, added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `map` operator to mutaate the object and assign the value to `CartQuantity`

```
var req = this.httpClient.get(url);
req.pipe(
   map(item => {
      item.CartQuantity = 1
   })
)
```

Comment: Based on his data type `item` should have been an "Array"  and there should had been an `item.forEach()` inside the `rxjs` map(). But anyway it works for him.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a loop anyway either when you are getting the response in your promise or When you are assigning the response to products. I am adding this answer because I saw that you are not instantiating `Product` class to assign to `products`, This means that `products: Products[]` will not actually be containing `Product` objects but rather a normal `{id: number, name: string, price: number}` Javascript Object(runtime assignment). If your `Product` class contains some method and you try to access that using 
say `this.products[0].someMethod()`, you will get errors.

You should be doing this instead:

```
getProducts() {
   this.ProductService.getAllProducts(
     (response) => {
        this.products = response.map((eachResponse) => {
            let newProd = new Product();  // anyway you are setting the default value as 1
             // can avoid this loop by directly assigning the props here.
            for (let key in eachResponse) { 
                newProd[key] = eachReponse[key];
            }
            return newProd 
        })
     });
}
```